# How to record all running browser screens via ffmpeg in Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-recorder

Am trying to record my browser screens to a video by using ffmpeg.I can record the whole screens. when I focused out to another window it records the new window. Want to record the browser actions inspite of in unfocused state

Comment: Show your command and the complete log. We can't give any suggestions if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I am running some browser instances inside a docker. I need to record the browser actions that happened inside docker.  Running this command `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 out.mov` is recording the whole screen . can i record only browser actions  ?

Comment: I doubt it is possible with avfoundation input device. As far as I know it will record what you see and not a discreet, independent window. If you were to use x11grab you could setup a separate, dedicated screen and record only that.